# cuda printing more lines even with same number of loops

Tags: cuda

I am exploring cuda but it seems the output prints more than it should

```
__global__ void gpu_Floyd(int *result, int N, int k)
{
    int j;
    int Row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int Col;

    if(Row < N) 
    {
        #if __CUDA_ARCH__>=200 
        printf("row value: %d, blkId : %d, blkDim : %d, thread : %d  \n", Row, blockIdx.y, blockDim.y, threadIdx.y); 
        #endif

    }
}    



      //CUDA Portion
    int Grid_Dim_x = 1, Grid_Dim_y = 1;
    int Block_Dim_x = 2, Block_Dim_y = 2;
    //int noThreads_x, noThreads_y;
    int *result = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N*N);
    int *d_result;
    memcpy(result, mat, sizeof(int)*N*N);

    dim3 Grid(Grid_Dim_x, Grid_Dim_y);
    dim3 Block(Block_Dim_x, Block_Dim_y, 1);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_result, N*N);
    int k;
    cudaMemcpy(d_result, result, N * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    for(k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    {
         gpu_Floyd<<<Grid, Block>>>(d_result, N, k);
    }
    cudaMemcpy(result, d_result, N*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Output:

```
row value: 0, blkId : 0, blkDim : 2, thread : 0  
row value: 0, blkId : 0, blkDim : 2, thread : 0  
row value: 1, blkId : 0, blkDim : 2, thread : 1  
row value: 1, blkId : 0, blkDim : 2, thread : 1  
row value: 0, blkId : 0, blkDim : 2, thread : 0  
row value: 0, blkId : 0, blkDim : 2, thread : 0  
row value: 1, blkId : 0, blkDim : 2, thread : 1  
row value: 1, blkId : 0, blkDim : 2, thread : 1
```

Shouldnt the output be only 2 lines instead of 8 lines as the for loop only iterate twice? How does the block dimension and grid dimension affect my output.

I would like the final output to only be

```
row value: 0, blkId : 0, blkDim : 2, thread : 0  
row value: 1, blkId : 0, blkDim : 2, thread : 1
```

Comment: Your question is good in that it has fairly complete code and you list both the output you get and the output you expected. But really, you should seek to gain some knowledge from  documentation before firing off a question on Stack Overflow. I have voted to close on the grounds that you did not show minimal knowledge of the subject matter.

Comment: I agree with Roger. The classical "CUDA By Example" book would smoothly introduce you to the topic of parallel programming on GPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Grid` variable is (1,1) meaning you are launching one block.
Your `Block` variable is (2,2) meaning you are launching 2x2 threads, i.e. a total of 4 threads per block.  Since there is only one block you are launching a total of 4 threads.

The code in a `__global__` kernel is executed by every thread.  Therefore each thread will execute (individually) the call to `printf` in your kernel.  Thus for each execution of your kernel there will be a total of 4 calls to `printf` (one per thread.)

Since you are launching your kernel twice, you get a total of 8 output lines generated by `printf`.

The behavior is expected.